# Update nested array object field in mongodb using spring boot

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

New to mongodb,
Tring to update multiple array object field of an document.
not getting expected result

Document Structure:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("4faaba123412d654fe83hg876"),
    "user_id" : 123456,
 
    "items" : [{
            Name:{
                    "id":1,
                    "item_name" : "my_item_one",
                    "price" : 20
            },
            Details:{
                    "Date" : "10/02/2022",
                    "Address":"test"
            }}],
            [{
            Name:{
                    "id":2,
                    "item_name" : "my_item_two",
                    "price" : 20
            },
            Details:{
                    "Date" : "10/02/2022",
                    "Address":"test"
            }}]
}
```

Based on id need to update date

Spring boot code

```
Query query = new Query(Criteria.where("user_id").is("123456").and("items")
.eleMatch(Criteria.where("items.Name.id").is(1)));
Update update = new Update().set("items.0.Details.Date", "29/01/2022");
mongoOperation.findAndModify(query, update, Items.class);
```

but when I run this query it is returning null
Can any one help on this
Thanks
,
Also tried

```
Query query = new Query(Criteria.where("user_id").is("123456").and("items")
.eleMatch(Criteria.where("items.Name.id").is(1)));
Update update = new Update().set("items.Details.Date", "29/01/2022");
mongoOperation.findAndModify(query, update, Items.class);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think your query doesn't find anything to update. try running the query as a "find" in java and see which document comes back. my hunch is that the "and eleMatch" part is wrong. just query for the entire document by the user_id, and execute the update on the specific field. also, the syntax on the update you described will update all items, you need to specify the index in the array. perhaps doing the update manually in java would be easier.

Comment: Thanks , Query query = new Query(Criteria.where("user_id").is("123456")) use this query